# Updating multi line chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, linechart

What is the correct way of updating the lines on a multi line chart? Simply binding new data and with a transition on 'd' attribute produces some weird transitions.

Here's a jsFiddle replicating that

```
function draw(data) {
    data.columns = ["date", "New York", "San Francisco", "Austin"];

    var cities = data.columns.slice(1).map(function(id) {
        return {
            id: id,
            values: data.map(function(d) {
                return {
                    date: d.date,
                    value: d[id]
                };
            })
        };
    });

    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
        return d.date;
    }));

    y.domain([
        d3.min(cities, function(c) {
            return d3.min(c.values, function(d) {
                return d.value;
            });
        }),
        d3.max(cities, function(c) {
            return d3.max(c.values, function(d) {
                return d.value;
            });
        })
    ]);

    z.domain(cities.map(function(c) {
        return c.id;
    }));

    xAxisG
        .transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

    yAxisG
        .transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y))

    var city = g.selectAll(".city")
        .data(cities)

    function drawLine(d) {
        d3.select(this).transition()
            .duration(duration)
            .attr("d", function(d) {
                d3.select(this);
                return line(d.values);
            });
    }

    city.enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "city")
        .append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .style("stroke", function(d) {
            return z(d.id);
        })
        .each(drawLine);

    city.select('.line')
        .each(drawLine);
};

var dataExample = [{"date": "2011-11-22", "New York": 50, "San Francisco": 0, "Austin": 57 }, ...];
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m3kvh29d/

Comment: Please read through http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and focus on "Help others reproduce the problem". With just two images it is impossible for us to know what the problem is. So please provide your code so we can reproduce it, preferably also a jsfiddle or similar.

Comment: Just updated with a jsFiddle replicating the issue

Comment: The problem is that you're trying to animate paths that do not feature the same number of points. This should help: https://bocoup.com/weblog/improving-d3-path-animation

Comment: Thank you for the article! Helps a lot in understanding how path animations works. I'll use the plugin from the article to solve the problem.
Also found a d3 example with a similar result
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3916621

Comment: Seems that d3-intepolate-path works only for linearCurve, solution from d3 example works with other curves to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I'm trying to animate paths that do not feature the same number of points.

This solution [1](https://bocoup.com/weblog/improving-d3-path-animation) works great only for linear curves, if it is not linear on a high number of points you still get 'knots' at the start.
This [2](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3916621) works with other types of curves (pathTween method) but is resource expensive :( with 5 lines with 65 columns I get a near 700ms delay.

Comment: Update: https://github.com/pbeshai/d3-interpolate-path was updated and it does a much better job at updating lines.